# Notify from trigger on pglogical replicated table

Tags: postgresql, replication, pglogical

I'm trying to setup a push-from-server functionality based on PostgreSQL, pglogical and PostgreSQL's listen-notify mechanism. On my replicated table I've setup a trigger that uses pg_notify to push messages to queue after insert. Altered the trigger to "enable always trigger". With this setup, the behavior is not what I expected.

After setting up a listen client (another postgresql console, also tried multiple python drivers, behavior is always the same), I don't get the notifications until I send another notification from another process that is not triggered by replication. Once I send the notification by hand, I get all the notifications pushed from the trigger alongside the one I've sent manually.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Running into the same thing with postgres 10.4 and logical replication. Did you ever figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug with PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/153243441449.1404.2274116228506175596%40wrigleys.postgresql.org). NOTIFY's coming from triggers that are triggered by logical replication don't properly trigger notifications. It's getting worked on.

Followed here from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457034/postgres-notify-not-working-with-logical-replication/).